# Flex: move dynamic child or element

Tags: apache-flex

It's possible to move a dynamic ctreated element or child?

Example:

Create childs:

```
 public function createChilds():void {
  for(var i:int=0; i < 10; i++) {
  newImage = new Image();
  newImage.source = myImages[i];
  mybox.addChild(newImage);
  }
 }
```

Move childs:

```
 public function moveChilds():void {
                for(var i:int=0; i < 10; i++) {
        mybox.getChildAt(i).move((mybox.getChildAt(i).x - 1), 0);
                }
    }
```

But I get an error message :(

Comment: This is something that can definitely be done. What is the error message you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `x` and `y` properties of the child to move them to the required coordinates.

For example,

```
mybox.getChildAt(i).x = mybox.getChildAt(i).x - 1;
mybox.getChildAt(i).y = 0;
```

Comment: thanks for tip, but it does not work inside <mx:HBox>. For example: <mx:HBox><mx:Image src="blabla.jpg"></mx:HBox> And when i use <mx:Canvas>, i can add only one image or only one image is displayed.

Comment: Sorry the move() should work and is almost functionally equivalent to setting x and y. Please post the error so others can take a look :)

Comment: Error: Call to a possibly undefined moveTo method through a reference with static type flash.display: DisplayObject.

Comment: It would not work inside an `HBox` because HBox automatically layouts all the children inside horizontally. And when you add a child to a canvas, it's by default added to x=0,y=0. So all the images must be on top of each other. What are you trying to achieve? Post the error please.

Comment: PS: i can move all static elements inside HBox but not dynamic

Comment: Post your complete code. You are trying to call `moveTo` method on a DisplayObject which DisplayObject does not have. `moveTo` is in Graphics class.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6122/discussion-between-ranhiru-cooray-and-eugen)